# b43-fwcutter install fails. No internet access. Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, networking, drivers, broadcom

I am trying to get my wifi or ethernet connection to work on Ubuntu 10.04. Neither will. I therefor have no internet access. There seems to be driver issue.

From what I've seen, the first step to resolving this is to install b43-fwcutter. Multiple sources state this, including the "official docs" about such.

Here's the problem - when I attempt this installation it fails because it apparently requires internet access! It uses wget in it's process. Why? How do I skip that? It's trying to get the file wl_apsta-3.130.20.0.o from a remote source. I have that file locally. I thought that am supposed to install that with b43-fwcutter AFTER b43-fwcutter is installed first?

COMMAND:

```
sudo dpkg -i /media/UBUNTUSB/pool/main/b/b43-fwcutter/*
```

RESULT:

```
(Reading database ... 122496 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace b43-fwcutter 1:012-1build1 (using .../b43-fwcutter_012-1build1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement b43-fwcutter ...
Setting up b43-fwcutter (1:012-1build1) ...
--2017-03-29 10:43:33--  http://downloads.openwrt.org/sources/wl_apsta-3.130.20.0.o
Resolving downloads.openwrt.org... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address `downloads.openwrt.org'
dpkg: error processing b43-fwcutter (--install):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 4
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 b43-fwcutter
```

Comment: Ubuntu 10.04 for the Desktop reached the end of its life May 9, 2013. You need a more recent release.

Comment: Thanks.  That's not an option for me.  I require it for a very specific purpose.

Answer (score 0):

So here's what happened. When you try to install b43-fwcutter for the FIRST TIME, a menu screen appears which says that it needs to install firmware that it can't be package with. Then, it asks "Y/N proceed?" Clicking yes results in this wget process. I wasn't paying close enough attention clearly! It then never shows that menu again when you try to reinstall. It simply appears to fail. It DOES, however, install despite this error displayed during that process!